# Mulesoft ConnectionManagementStrategy Class with additional parameters

Tags: java, mule, mule-component

I am writing my first Mulesoft Connector.  I am trying to implement @ConnectionManagementStrategy.  I have referenced:

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Connection+Management

I am trying to implement a connection to a custom web service.  For my client, I need to specify username, password, and endpoint.  I am able to get the connection to work if I hardcode the endpoint.  However, we may be re-using this connector for other services and I want to be able to configure the endpoint.  Per the documentation, the devkit calls/creates the class instance automatically.  I want to to be able to pass a an argument to the constructor based on a configurable property in the @Connector or pass an additional argument to the @Connect method.

I am not finding in the documentation how to customize these methods.

My @Connector:

```
    @Connector(name="testContactConnector", friendlyName = "Test Contact Connector")
public class Contact {

    @Configurable
    @Default("https://my.cool.service")
    public String webServiceEndpoint;

    @ConnectionStrategy
    private Connection connection;

    public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return this.connection;
    }

    @Processor
    public String getSessionID() throws Exception {
        return this.connection.connectionID();
    }

}
```

My @ConnectionManagementStrategy:

```
@ConnectionManagement(friendlyName = "Contact Service Connection")
public class Connection {

    private String serviceEndpoint, username, password, sessionID;
    private Service service;

    public Connection() {
    }

    @Connect
    @TestConnectivity
    public void connect(@ConnectionKey String username, @Password String password)
        throws ConnectionException {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

        try {
            this.service = Service.Logon(this.username, this.password, this.serviceEndpoint);
            this.sessionID = this.service.getSession();
        } catch (Exception error) {
            throw new ConnectionException(ConnectionExceptionCode.INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS, null, error.getMessage(), error);
        }
    }

    @Disconnect
    public void disconnect() {
        if(this.service != null) {
            try {
                this.service.killSession();
            } catch (Exception error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                this.service = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @ValidateConnection
    public boolean isConnected() {
        try {
            return (this.service != null && this.service.getSession() != null);
        } catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @ConnectionIdentifier
    public String connectionID() {
        try {
            return this.service.getSession();
        } catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
Fat fingered a character in the example code

**THE SOLUTION I CAME UP WITH PER THE DOCUMENTATION PROVIDED IN THE ANSWER**

In the @ConnectionManagement class I added the following property:

```
@Configurable
@Default("https://your.web.service")
public String webServiceEndpoint;
```

In the @Connect method I referenced that property:

```
@Connect
@TestConnectivity
public void connect(@ConnectionKey String username, @Password String password) throws ConnectionException {
  this.username = username;
  this.password = password;
  try {
        this.service = Service.Logon(this.username, this.password, this.webServiceEndpoint);
        this.sessionID = this.service.getSessionID();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        throw new ConnectionException(ConnectionExceptionCode.INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS, null, error.getMessage(), error);
    }
}
```

In my config file I have the following setting the values:

```
<myconnector:config name="config" webServiceEndpoint="http://my.custom.service" username="foo" password="foo"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-cookbook-tutorial/#_adding_connection_management) you can find an easy example how to implement connection management. Furthermore this documentation provides an easy step by step guide on how to build a connector from start to finish. HTH.

Comment: I gave an up tick as this is good documentation but it does not answer my specific question (or at least I am not find the documentation that does).  I want to be able send an additional parameter to the connection management strategy class, not just create a connection.

Comment: On further look, i found the answer in your documentation.  I was able to accomplish what I needed by adding a @Configurable element to my ConnectionManagement class.  I could set the value of this in the configuration element in the config file.  I will edit my post with an example but thanks for the documentation, it answered the question!

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple @ConnectionKey elements, and the names can be anything.

This for example is perfectly valid:

```
@Connect
@TestConnectivity
public void connect(@ConnectionKey String composedKeyItem1,
                    @ConnectionKey String composedKeyItem2)
```

Also you can use the @Configurable elements, since they will be initialized before the @Connect is called.

Comment: But how do I tell my connector to pass the custom attribute to the constructor if the devkit automatically handles instantiating the object?